# No input file specified after enabling multi site

Tags: multisite, htaccess, wp-config

I am getting this error after enabling Multisite "No input file specified.", I can't find a solution in the internet, I hope you can help me.
I have this in my htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

and on my wp-config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'testdomainforrevol8.dk');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Here's  my [website](http://testdomainforrevol8.dk/)

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: How can I disable a plugin if I can't access the dashboard?

Comment: because I can't access the dashboard, I just renamed the themes and plugins, but it did not work.

Comment: This isn't error message from WordPress core. From quick search it seems to be related to server stack. Those `.htaccess` rules don't seem to be natively generated by WP, have you tried just removing them and see if that gets you to dashboard at least? PS your site seems to work now? Was this resolved?